# Show {{ value }} except special one in AngularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

After SPAN click my DIV get this category title , but in one case , when category.title is 'Favorite' (or category.id = '1',its the same) i need ignore it in DIV and don't change the value on it.

How can i realize that ? 
Thanks in advance

My HTML :

```
<div> {{ selections.category.title }} </div>
<span ng-repeat="category in categories track by category.id" ng-click="selectCategory(category)">
      ... 
</span>
```

My controller :

```
$scope.selectCategory = function selectCategory(category) {
   $scope.selections.category = category;
   ... 
}
```

EDIT.

I need only ignore it in DIV's text , not ignore click on this element .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div> {{ selectedTitle  }} </div>

$scope.selectCategory = function selectCategory(category) {
  if(category.title !== 'Favorite' && category.id !== '1') {
   $scope.selectedTitle = category.title;
  }
  $scope.selections.category = category;
  ...      
}
```

Comment: Hi , in this way i have some problem...  this part "$scope.selections.category = category"  must be selected every time . I need only ignore text changes in DIV when selected category is 'Favorite'

Comment: That's kinda weird approach. I think you need to keep separate variable for this div then, if it only should show the title. I changed the answer accodringly.

Comment: Except title changes , this part of code also do many another thinks "$scope.selections.category = category" so i cant ignore it .

Comment: Yes, i changed it so it does not ignore the rest of the code. You just save your title in `$scope.selectedTitle` and it changes only if selected is not favorite.